# Cursive editor gives classpath exception when trying to run clojure project that uses figwheel

Tags: clojure, cursive, figwheel

Trying to get a project that uses figwheel running in Cursive. I can get everything running on the command line using `run -m clojure.main script/figwheel.clj` but when I follow the instructions for running within Cursive I get the following error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate figwheel_sidecar/repl_api__init.class or figwheel_sidecar/repl_api.clj on classpath.

Does anyone know why this works on the command line and not within Cursive? I believe I followed the directions that the project provided. Do I need to set my classpath somewhere in Cursive.

Comment: can you please link the instructions you are following?

Comment: Give us the full command you're using. Do you happen to use profiles? They don't really work.

Comment: https://github.com/awkay/om-tutorial is what I am trying to get running in Cursive. I don't think I am using profiles. I have now shutdown Cursive and re-started, re-ran the project with the same run configuration I was receiving the error from, and now it seems to work. Not sure why I had to shut down Cursive. Thank you both for taking the time to help me out.